# Where is Rhythmbox when I close the window?

Tags: lubuntu, rhythmbox

I use Rhythmbox to play songs, but when I clicked the top-right close <kbd>X</kbd>,
it disappeared, but the song is still playing.

Where can I find it?

PS. I use Lubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

When you clicked the X in the top-right corner, you just closed the program window, not quit the program. This allows you to play music while not having the window open, a quite useful feature actually.

Just start Rythmbox again and it will pop right back up where you left it!

Comment: Rhythmbox is actually located at the sound menu, in the top right corner of the screen, where you change the volume. You can access Rhythmbox from there, too.

Comment: @Jorge Suárez de Lis : Yes, but only using Unity. He stated that he was using Lubuntu, so he is probably using LXDE, which doesn't do that, it has a separate item down in the lower right-hand corner on the status bar.

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

You can make it like this,
First exit/close Rhythmbox,
then download [rhythmbox-tray-icon.zip](https://github.com/mendhak/rhythmbox-tray-icon/raw/master/rhythmbox-tray-icon.zip) 
and 
extract its contents into ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins.

Start Rhythmbox. Go to Edit > Plugins.
Find 'Tray Icon' in the plugins list and enable it. 
A Rhythmbox icon appears in the notification area.

I tested on my Linux LXLE working nicely...:D

adapted from here:
http://code.mendhak.com/rhythmbox-tray-icon/